# In Pandas, how to get multiple subset data frame based on groupby criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

For example; I have a data frame like this

```
ID v1 v2 v3
1   0  0  1
1   1  1  1
1   1  0  1
1   1  1  0
2   0  1  1
2   0  0  1
2   1  1  0
3   1  0  1
3   1  1  1
```

What I'm interested in is to get a list of data frame such that each data-frame is a subset of original based on the groupby['ID']

So looking for something returns a list of data frame `result` in which

```
result[0]
ID v1 v2 v3
1   0  0  1
1   1  1  1
1   1  0  1
1   1  1  0

result[1]
ID v1 v2 v3
2   0  1  1
2   0  0  1
2   1  1  0

result[2]
ID v1 v2 v3
3   1  0  1
3   1  1  1
```

Right now, what I'm doing is loop iteration through `ID`

```
for id in df['ID']:
    result.append(df[df['ID'] == id])
```

But there might be lots of `ID` and this not very efficient (note that each `ID` might have different number of data points). Any thoughts ?  Thanks

Comment: `result = {k:d for k,d in df.groupby('ID')}` gives you a dictionary, or `result = [d for _,d in df.groupby('ID')]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for such quick reply; yes it works ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
d = dict([*df.groupby('ID')])
d[1]
Out[160]: 
   ID  v1  v2  v3
0   1   0   0   1
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   0   1
3   1   1   1   0
```

Comment: @piRSquared thank you sir ~it has been a long time for me to work it out ~